# Popup modal :Submitting url in magento 2

Tags: php, frontend, url, magento2.2

I have created **custom link** using **popup modal**. I need to placed this link in My **Account page->My Orders** and next to Reorder link. Like below
[image]

While clicking **cancel** it **shows** an **popup** window which consist **text area** and **submit** button. While clicking submit,It should save in DB. I have written code, in my Controller file to save the message in DB, But I don't know where I need to give the submit url in below file. Please provide me a solution.

Thanks in advance

**history.phtml**

```
<div>
                                <a href="#" class="click-me">Cancel</a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
                                <textarea>
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                                require(
                                        [
                                            'jquery',
                                            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
                                        ],
                                        function (
                                                $,
                                                modal
                                                ) {
                                            var options = {
                                                type: 'popup',
                                                responsive: true,
                                                innerScroll: true,
                                                title: 'Reason for Cancelled the item',
                                                buttons: [{
                                                        text: $.mage.__('submit'),
                                                        class: '',
                                                        click: function () {
                                                            this.closeModal();
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                            };

                                            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
                                            $(".click-me").on('click', function () {
                                                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
                                            });

                                        }
                                );
                            </script>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace XXX\SalesOrder\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

//use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action
{

    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, Order $order, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->order = $order;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = 3;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('I need to get message here');// I need to get textarea message here
        $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $order->save();

        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `<form>` inside `popup-modal` div

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="click-me">Cancel</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
      <form action="<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'frontname/controllername/actionname';?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
                <textarea id="reason" name="reason"></textarea>
      </form>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                //innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Reason for Cancelled the item',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('submit'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function(data) {

                        var form_data = jQuery("#form-validate").serialize();


                        console.log(form_data);
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'frontname/controllername/actionname';?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function(data) {

                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                                console.log('no response !');
                            }
                        });

                        this.closeModal();

                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $(".click-me").on('click', function() {
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my post, see that.. In my Block I have mentioned the getSaleCollection function , then How do i call getBaseUrl function ??  Because I did not mention any function like getBaseUrl... Please Explain

Comment: getBaseUrl() function is core function which can be used in any phtml file so no need to define in you block

Comment: I have added  my controller file . But while clicking submit it is failed to hit controller . see the updated post

Comment: add like this in form action and  ajax call <?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'frontname/index/index';?>  change frontname with your frontname

Comment: Thank you, It works good, But i need to get text area message in  addStatusHistoryComment in my controller... Any idea about it

Comment: to get text area value in controller use this $data=$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69327/discussion-between-jayashree-and-mansi).